# Problem with removing punctuation and space

Tags: c++

I cant remove the punctuation like " ’ " and some space  in this program. Also this code has a problem with removing " ’ ". What is the problem.

**Input**

> sfsvh@ sfs%do ksh#jksn ^ gs ohgsds.dadadf.wfa :) ssafwfdad=.=adsdsg ^.^hosgnskjh ^^ skodsfsh v sfs

**Expected Output**

> sfsvhsfsdokshjksngsohgsdsdadadfwfassafwfdadadsdsghosgnskjhskodsfshvsfsodsfshvsfs

**MY program Output**

> sfsvhsfsdokshjksngsohgsdsdadadfwfassafwfdadadsdsghosgnskjhskodsfshvsfsodsfsh v sfs

**MY Code**

```
string  palindrome,input_str;
getline(cin,input_str);
remove_if(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), ::isspace);
transform(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), input_str.begin(), ::tolower);
input_str.erase (std::remove_if (input_str.begin (), input_str.end (), ::ispunct), input_str.end ());
palindrome.append(input_str);
cout<<input_str<<"\n";
```

Comment: hint: are your two uses of `remove_if` the same? does one work whilst the other doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `remove_if` doesn't alter the string. You forgot to call `.erase` before:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string input_str = "sfsvh@ sfs%do ksh#jksn ^ gs ohgsds.dadadf.wfa :) ssafwfdad=.=adsdsg ^.^hosgnskjh ^^ skodsfsh v sfs";

    input_str.erase(std::remove_if(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), ::isspace), input_str.end());
    std::transform(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), input_str.begin(), ::tolower);
    input_str.erase(std::remove_if(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), ::ispunct), input_str.end());

    std::cout << input_str << "\n";
}
```

***output***

> sfsvhsfsdokshjksngsohgsdsdadadfwfassafwfdadadsdsghosgnskjhskodsfshvsfs

---

You seem to have trouble with the character `’`. That is, because it is not within the unsigned char ascii range. (`’` is the unicode "right single quotation mark" = `\x2019`). Use wide string utilities to capture this symbol:

```
std::wstring input_str = L"sfsvh@ sfs%do ksh#jksn’ ^ gs ohgsds.dadadf.wfa :) ssafwfdad=.=adsdsg ^.^hosgnskjh ^^ skodsfsh v sfs";

input_str.erase(std::remove_if(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), ::iswspace), input_str.end());
std::transform(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), input_str.begin(), ::towlower);
input_str.erase(std::remove_if(input_str.begin(), input_str.end(), ::iswpunct), input_str.end());

std::wcout << input_str << L'\n';
```

Note the `std::wstring`, `L"..."`, `::iswspace`, `:towlower`, `::iswpunct` and `std::wcout` changes here.

---

using [`regex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) does the whole removing in one line of code. It removes any non-word characters (`^0-9a-zA-Z`), here.

```
input_str = std::regex_replace(input_str, std::regex("[^\\w]"), "");
```

the wide string equivalent:

```
input_str = std::regex_replace(input_str, std::wregex(L"[^\\w]"), L"");
```

Comment: How about removing " ’ ", ispunct() is false and I has done the comparison of ascii code but the output is so strange

Comment: @ChakWingMak I included a section discussing it. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tried out the wide string utilities of your code ,  the output is 
sfsvhsfsdokshjksn'gsohgsdsdadadfwfassafwfdadadsdsghosgnskjhskodsfshvsfs

Comment: please post that exact code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) so I can take a look at that.